# Use Cordova or Ionic2?

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I have to build an application running on all platforms (windows phone, blackberry, ios, and android).

I have heard a lot about Ionic2, but Ionic2 doesn't support BlackBerry, or windows phone.

I know that Cordova is the low-level, and ionic2 is build on top of Cordova. However, Cordova supports all platforms (including the blackberry or windows phone).

So, I need to use Cordova, even Ionic2 is better?

Comment: Ionic 2 does fully support windows phones now :)

Comment: ya, thanks for the info. But ionic2 does not support BlackBerry. Confirm?

Comment: I can also confirm that. I think Sencha Touch may support all platforms but I have never used it before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically **you can use Android emulator on Blackberry** which works really well. My friend use many Android apps through this. Here is some guide: http://crackberry.com/how-install-android-apps-and-apk-files-blackberry-os-1021

**Ionic2 is much more usable than pure Cordova.** Cordova is just clean WebView where you can use plugins but nothing more - no predefined UI elements, transitions, navigation stack, etc. It's very hard to create app which looks like a native app.

Ionic2 works awesome on iPhone and new Androids (Android >= 5), but it's worse on Windows Universal platform. There are many bugs while using it on the phone, slow scrolling if you use ion-option-button, side menu problems, etc. 
**Ionic on Windows Phone is definitely not production ready** (but it's still on beta).

Comment: Thanks for your info. Very useful. I also want to use ionic2. Can we use ionic2 and still use Cordova plugins?

Comment: Yes you can and it's recommended to use it that way. Ionic is framework primarily based on Cordova. And the best way how to add some cordova plugin in Ionic 2 is to use Ionic Native: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/

Comment: There is not so many tutorial how to build windows 10 with ionic2. Apparently ionic2 only supports windows 10. I tried to install on windows 8.1 device. It's totally a blank page. Probably, I need to come back to ionic1 to support with the lower windows phone version (e.g., 8.0, 8.1) ??

Comment: Windows Phones lower than version 10 are not supported in Ionic 2 and even in Ionic 1. Maybe you could run some easy apps on WP 8, but probably it doesn't worth for it... It will be hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search to see the BlackBerry market share in 2016 and I found this link http://bgr.com/2016/05/23/smartphone-market-share-q1-2016/
Besides that looks like BlackBerry is moving to Android http://money.cnn.com/2016/07/26/technology/blackberry-dtek50/

With Ionic 2 you can support the major platforms at the market and have solid components to create amazing hybrid apps.

Comment: I wish the client can understand. However, 30% employees at the client's company are equipped by BlackBerry (Blackberry OS).

Comment: The project is not so big, so I will stick with ionic1 who can support all platforms (including BlackBerry)